# Swift enum segmentation fault

Tags: swift, enums, segmentation-fault

I have to following code:

```
groupListeningObject = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(groupJoinedOrLeftNotificationName, object: nil, queue: nil) { [weak self] notification in
    if let notificationArray = notification.object as? [AnyObject]  {
        let joinedOrLeft = JoinOrLeave(rawValue: notificationArray[1] as Int)
        if joinedOrLeft == .Join {
            //some code
        } 
    }
}
```

This gives a segmentation fault error, but if I modify the if statement as follows:

```
if joinedOrLeft == JoinOrLeave.Join
```

there will be no error.
 I thought I can use the short version of an enum in an if statement, but the compiler doesn't like it. Why can't I use the shorter version of enums, what am I missing here?

Comment: I'd count that as compiler bug. Swift (and SourceKitService) starts getting picky in some places when you don't supply declarations. The SKS even starts endless loops for some simple implicit dictionaries.

Comment: It certainly is a bug if the compiler crashes. Here it seems to be caused by `joinedOrLeft` being an *optional* (`JoinOrLeave?`) and as a workaround you can use optional binding `if let joinedOrLeft = ...`. Also it seems to work correctly in Xcode 6.3 beta.