# Segmentation fault 11 when building for profiling in a swift enum

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, enums, compiler-errors

I have an app that works both in the simulator and on my iphone/ipad. But when I build it for profiling I get a segmentation fault 11 in a file where an enum is defined. This is the enum:

```
internal enum PaletteType: Int {
    case Normal = 0
    case Darkened = 1
    case Lighter = 2
    case Deuteranopia = 3
    case Protanopia = 4
    case Tritanopia = 5

    func colorDeficiency() -> Bool {
        switch self {
        case .Normal:
            return false
        case .Darkened:
            return false
        case .Lighter:
            return false
        case .Deuteranopia:
            return true
        case .Protanopia:
            return true
        case .Tritanopia:
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

I have the idea that it has to do with the `switch self` statement. If I remove the switch statement and just always return false the compiler doesn't give the segmentation fault 11. But the weird thing is that I have another enum defined that also uses the `switch self` statement, but that doesn't give this fault.

One addition: in the fault description it also says: "Running pass 'Simplify the CFG' on function '@_TFO8Dathanna11PaletteType15colorDeficiencyfS0_FT_Sb'"

One more thing: I do know that there is a way around this, by replacing the switch self statement for an if statement. Then it does work. I just like to find out why it doesn't work with the switch statement in this instance while it does work in other.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I had segmentation error as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28559192/swift-enum-segmentation-fault with enums, what if you try to use the full name of the enum in the cases, like PaletteType.Normal?

Comment: I did try to use the full names. Still the same fault.

Comment: Have you tried changing the scope of the enum by removing the internal keyword? Just a thought.

Comment: Mellson: I just tried. Same fault. But thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Try putting a default case on the swift?

Comment: I copied your enum into a separate file and had no problem in a new project. Have you tried:

1. Cleaning Derived Data?
2. Are you on the latest Xcode 6.3 Beta? Ir compiled for profiling for me under Xcode 6.3.

Comment: I'm not using the beta xcode. Had some issues with beha's in the past. I'll see if I can test it on a separate install if 6.3 beta. Maybe it's already fixed. I did however cleaned the project and I recently cleaned derived data folder, but I can try again tomorrow. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Chuthan20: thanks for the suggestion, but that doesn't work either.